# Select elements from numpy array based on a list of lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have a numpy array like this:

```
arr = np.array([[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4])
```

I also have a list that determines the intended lengths:

```
lens = [1,2,3,4]
```

Is there an elegant and Pythonic way to return a new array, with each corresponding element selected using the `lens` variable?

The output should be:

```
[[1], [2,2],[3,3,3], [4,4,4,4]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If each Numpy `arr` list element size is less than 5 this works.

Use `zip`:

```
[a[:i].tolist() for a, i in zip(arr, lens)]
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: Not sure if each arr list elements size is more than or equal to 5 not working. Attribute Error coming

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible solution:

```
res = []
for a,i in zip(arr, lens):
    res.append(a[:i].tolist())
print(res)
```

Comment: This doesn't print any output as of now. So I edited it to print output by declaring a res variable which is an empty list to start with.

Comment: Using your method, the output is like this   [[1]]
[[1], [2, 2]]
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `arr` is equal in length as `lens`:

```
[arr[i][:v].tolist() for i,v in enumerate(lens)]
```

***Output:***    `[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]`